# What is AVPlayerItem timeout value?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, avplayer, avplayeritem

In the documentation, https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2436/_index.html it is mentioned

Timeout Errors:

When resources such as the master playlist, media playlists, media files and content keys are requested there are timeouts defined. A failure to get a response within this timeout will cause timeout errors.

What is the value of this timeout?